# C# Windows Form - access code

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to know where I can access the basic code, for example a "NumericUpDown" Element.
What I want to do:
Add Code to my NumericUpDown Element, for example:
Set the "Maximum"-Value to a variable embedded inside my Formclass code.

The Reason why I cant to it right now:
I just can access the NumericUpDown Element just in the Design View right now. There I can Input a value, but can't set it to the amount stored in a variable.

I just know, that If I double click the field, I get a "ValueChanged" Method into my code. But what I need to know: How can I access the "basic" Code of the NumericUpDown Element, where I could set the "Maximum"-Property?

I'm relatively new to programming. And I'm quite overwhelmed with a lot of things... So I COULD google for the problem but it would just take me way to much time.
Since I guess it's an easy answer for you guys, I post it here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but S.O. doesn't work this way, it's a website where developers who already put energy and time in their own issues go to seek help, not a "Do-it-for-me" charity group.

Comment: Is this your serious answer?
I mean it really seems like an easy answer to give. I just need to know where I can access that code, where I can find it.

I don't know what I should google for, to find an answer.

I don't want you to make the code for me, just explain me how I do this in a proper way.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano He asked "HOW" to access a property. It's just a simple answer but what does this has to do with "Do it for me" ?

Comment: As he stated in his question, his doubt could easily be solved searching google. He "has no time for that" and hence shows no sign of effort.

Comment: Googling it would take too much time? That statement really pisses me off. You have shown zero effort. You do not learn anything if this is the approach you're heading for. Read the FAQ.

Comment: Well, you read everything the way you want, don't you?
I said it would take me too much time, the reason why is, because I don't know what I should google for exactly, because I didn't even know how the "name the problem" properly. 
Btw - user3576526 helped my out there, even provided a good keyword to google for.
The funniest thing is: you wasted more time explaining yourself than you would have with just answering my simple question (simple it would have been for you of course).
Good job!

Comment: Our issue here has never been "time", S.O. has rules and regulations on how it should be properly used, just because it takes less time, it doesn't mean it's the correct thing to do (like many things in life).

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano He said he's new. He didn't know how to search for it. It's the same. I'm musician. If you want to start making electronic music and make a question like: "what do I need to make my music sound more realistic" you will receive answers like "Search for it in google". Then you will find thing like "Echo with reverb" "Modify Low and high band rates" in google and you will be like wtf. If you search in google for "Low and High Band rates" you will find stuff from wikipedia -_- 
He just need to know the basic stuff to know how to improve on searching!

Comment: As you can see this question has been put on Hold. Why? Because it's against S.O. regulations. It's not me who makes the rules, but if you want to take part to the community, you should abide by those rules, or try to change them here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Control's objects attributes by it's name.

For example:

`NumericUpDown1` <- It's the name of your Control

In your C# code you can access all of it's attribtes and methods by puttin a period after it's name:

```
NumericUpDown1.Maximun = 100;
NumericUpDown1.Width = 250;
NumericUpDown1.Height = 10;
```

etc. You can serach it by "Control Properties" in google. Luck and effort! :P Remember to try and search a bit before asking. Don't wait for others to make your job. Luck! ^.^

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either :) Guess SO is not for normal, helpful people

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Yes you're right, I just wouldn't have known what to google for (control properties helps of course) :)

Comment: Don't worry ^.^
You're new, so yes, you don't know where to start :P

Comment: The answer helped a lot though... and I think someone who knows those basics doesn't even need to think about it.
So I think think, for someone who cares and has the time, it's not a problem to answer such a question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access source code of components, but it won't help you. every component has interface and you can use it's interface to interact with it. Also you can override some methods of component to change their behavior.